# Acumatica upgrade from 18.210 to 18.217 (Unable to cast object of type 'PX.Data.PXResult`2[PX.Objects.FS.FSServiceOrder,PX.Objects.AR.Customer]'

Tags: c#, acumatica

The source code of the button action is

````
public PXAction<FSServiceOrder> CreateSalesOrder;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Sales Order", Enabled = true, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXProcessButton]

        public virtual IEnumerable createSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            foreach (FSServiceOrder fso in adapter.Get())
            {
                Customer cust = (Customer)PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<FSServiceOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(this.Base);
                if (cust == null)
                {
                    string exc = "Invalid customer ID";
                    throw new PXException(exc);
                }
                yield return fso;
            }
            SOOrderEntry docgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
            PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate ()
            {
                Customer customer = (Customer)PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<FSServiceOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(this.Base);
                FSServiceOrder fsServiceORderRow = this.Base.ServiceOrderRecords.Current;
                FSSODetPart rows = this.Base.ServiceOrderDetParts.Current;

                CurrencyInfo info = PXSelect<CurrencyInfo, Where<CurrencyInfo.curyInfoID, Equal<Current<FSServiceOrder.curyInfoID>>>>.Select(this.Base);
                info.CuryInfoID = null;
                bool createso = false;
                foreach (FSSODetPart parts in SelectItems(fsServiceORderRow.RefNbr))
                {
                    if (parts == null)
                    {
                        createso = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        createso = true;
                    }
                }

                if (createso == true)
                {
                    SOOrder doc = new SOOrder();                    
                    doc.OrderType = "SM";
                    doc = docgraph.Document.Insert(doc);
                    doc.OrderDate = fsServiceORderRow.OrderDate;
                    doc.CustomerRefNbr = fsServiceORderRow.RefNbr;
                    doc.CustomerOrderNbr = fsServiceORderRow.CustPORefNbr;
                    nbr = fsServiceORderRow.RefNbr;
                    doc.OrderDesc = fsServiceORderRow.DocDesc;
                    doc.TermsID = customer.TermsID;
                    doc.CustomerID = fsServiceORderRow.CustomerID;
                    doc = docgraph.Document.Update(doc);

                    foreach (FSSODetPart parts in SelectItems(fsServiceORderRow.RefNbr))
                    {
                        if (parts == null) return;
                        SOLine tran = new SOLine();
                        tran = docgraph.Transactions.Insert(tran);
                        if (tran != null)
                        {
                            tran.InventoryID = parts.InventoryID;
                            tran.SubItemID = parts.SubItemID;
                            tran.OrderQty = parts.OrderQty;
                            tran.UOM = parts.UOM;
                            tran.CuryUnitPrice = parts.CuryUnitPrice;
                            tran.TaxCategoryID = parts.TaxCategoryID;
                            tran.SiteID = parts.SiteID;
                            tran.LocationID = parts.LocationID;
                            tran.IsFree = parts.IsFree;
                            tran.ProjectID = parts.ProjectID;
                            tran.TaskID = parts.TaskID;
                            tran.ManualPrice = parts.ManualPrice;
                        }
                        tran = docgraph.Transactions.Update(tran);
                    }
                    docgraph.Save.Press();
                    docgraph.Document.Current = docgraph.Document.Search<SOOrder.orderNbr, SOOrder.orderType>(doc.OrderNbr, doctype);                    
                }
            });
        }```
While the error being displayed in trace is
````

19/02/2020 7:53:31 AM Error:
Unable to cast object of type 'PX.Data.PXResult`2[PX.Objects.FS.FSServiceOrder,PX.Objects.AR.Customer]' to type 'PX.Objects.FS.FSServiceOrder'.

at PX.Objects.FS.ServiceOrderEntry_Extension.d__3.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__32.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__32.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__32.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__32.MoveNext()
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)

```
I am still new to acumatica. I'll really appreciate the help
```

Comment: Have you tried turning it on and off again :P just kidding, is all your customization unpublished?... If customization is published during upgrades issues occur

Comment: Yes, all my customization are published

Comment: Does the error occur when the 'CreateSalesOrder' action is invoked? If that's the case, you can remove some code until the error disappear to identify the source of the error. That an upgrade happen is very rarely the root cause of errors, it does require some debugging to pinpoint the issue. Also as JvD stated, you must re-publish customization after update, that the published check is checked doesn't mean they have been re-published.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I have deduced the error is coming from this section of the code and have not yet identified the main problem `foreach (FSServiceOrder fso in adapter.Get())
            {
               Customer cust = (Customer)PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<FSServiceOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(this.Base);
                if (cust == null)
                {
                    string exc = "Invalid customer ID";
                    throw new PXException(exc);
                }
                yield return fso;
            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided in the comments, try with this alternative approach for the "Invalid Customer ID" validation:

Replace this section:

```
 foreach (FSServiceOrder fso in adapter.Get())
            {
                Customer cust = (Customer)PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<FSServiceOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(this.Base);
                if (cust == null)
                {
                    string exc = "Invalid customer ID";
                    throw new PXException(exc);
                }
                yield return fso;
            }
```

With this one:

```
FSServiceOrder currentServiceOrder = this.Base.ServiceOrderRecords.Current;

if (currentServiceOrder != null && currentServiceOrder.CustomerID != null)
{
                Customer cust = PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Customer.bAccountID>>>>.Select(this.Base, currentServiceOrder.CustomerID);
                if (cust == null)
                {
                    string exc = "Invalid customer ID";
                    throw new PXException(exc);
                }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm so grateful. With a little addition it worked. You guys are the best